# How do I "reverse" a gitignore file pattern in a subtree subdirectory?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-subtree

I have a repo that contains a subtree that has some build and config files.

```
main
├── .gitignore
└── build (subtree)
    ├── .gitignore
    └── config.user.json
    └── config.site.json
└── index.js
```

I would like to **ignore** the `config.user.json` from both the `main` repo and `build` subtree, but **keep** `config.site.json` in the main repo, but **ignore** it in the `build` subtree.

#### main/.gitignore

```
!build/config.site.json # (this is supposed to reverse the ignore)
build/config.user.json
```

#### build/.gitignore

```
build/config.site.json
build/config.user.json
```

Is this possible, or should I put my config files in a different folder that the `build`. I have a feeling that the .gitignore in the subtree will override the .gitignore in the main repo and not the other way around.

REF: [Git Subtree Specific Ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923530/git-subtree-specific-ignoring)

Cheers

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Once you ignore something in a subtree you cannot unignore it at the top-level. In the linked REF the situation is opposite — unignore something in a subtree that's ignored at the top-level; that's possible but not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have to work something else out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to work that way. The Git documentation on gitignore says (emphasis mine)

> Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern. When deciding whether to ignore a path, Git normally checks gitignore patterns from multiple sources, with the following order of precedence, from highest to lowest (within one level of precedence, **the last matching pattern decides the outcome**):
>
> - Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being **overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file**.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore